# Is column heading equivalent to named range in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

A point that I seek to clarify is if the column name (heading of column) is equivalent of the named range? For instance, I take the cursor to A, the button (where I am supposed to put the name of the named range) to the left of the function reads A1. As the web version of Excel does not support creating named ranges, will A1 work as a named range?

[image]

[image]

Comment: please upload images directly to superuser.com using the upload image in the edit box. Uploading images to other websites is forbidden because those links will rot and render the question invalid. Besides people will avoid clicking external links

Answer (score 1):

No.

You have a couple of possible workarounds:

1. Create Tables (which the web version can do) and use Headers. Then the headers of the columns can be used very, very much like a Named Range could be used. Not exactly, but in many of the same ways, and it's pretty likely that will take care of whatever issue led to this question with the example given.
2. Open the file in a desktop version and create the Named Ranges you need. The web version can use already existing Named Ranges. It just can't create them. So as awkward as going back and forth would be and with all the delays that would likely ensue, it is a viable method. As author John Ringo might write:  "For certain values of 'viable.'"

The following URL is a link to a MS site so it isn't likely to be lost any time soon. It gives many of the capabilities of the web version and mentions some of the drawbacks along the way:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-online-service-description/excel-online

But no, in no way is "A1" a Named Range, nor, for that matter, could it ever be as it is a valid cell address and even the desktop version will not allow those as names for Named Ranges.

Comment: To build on your second bullet, is it viable to create a template of named ranges that you can modify from the web version?  Sometimes you just don't have a PC available for use, as appalling as that may sound.